# How can I revert R Studio for Mac editor to default?

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I just installed R Studio on my mac (was previously using on my virtual Windows machine). I am taking a class in which we learn to use R. The fix() function was demonstrated and when I ran it on my dataset it opened up an editor that was pretty ugly and done in X11 - that is, X11 launched automatically. The person next to me ran the same function but on her computer the pretty and I assume default R editor popped up. I have searched the internet and the options/preferences within R but cannot figure out how to both find out what the default would be if I did not have X11 installed AND change the editor in R Studio back to that program.

I can handle basic command line stuff if this is buried in a file I have to access through terminal/fancy preferences.

Has anyone run into this or have an idea of where to look? I don't want to use a text editor; just that nice-looking default program. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have RStudio set as the default program to open .R files?

Comment: I have the R GUI as the default program for `.R` files but the RStudio editor still comes up when I use `fix()` inside it. Not sure what the settings are for that.

Comment: Is this related to the "editor" option?

Comment: @David: I did not, but I changed it and tried fix() and edit() again and still got the ugly X11 window.

Comment: @Dason: I'm not sure what the "editor" option is. If you are asking if it is the same thing that opens when you use edit() (i.e. not just fix()), then yes!

Comment: I know you probably don't want to hear that, but simply don't use `fix` (or `edit`). It's one of the functions you need less the more experienced you become with R until you don't use it at all.

Comment: @SeñorO I'm assuming by "RStudio editor" you mean the default editor that RStudio has defined.  My guess is that you're accessing RSTudio's `.Rprofile` or other startup file when running from the `R.app` GUI.  But, as Roland said, manually editing data files is about the least efficient (or robust) way to do so. Use the `[<-` operator instead.

Comment: I don't really use `fix`, but it's not obvious to me how `[<-` does the same thing as `fix` (i.e. edit functions), can you explain?

Comment: @SeñorO Editing code is very easily done directly in almost any editor of your choice, many of which can be set up to `source` code from within the editor.  The `fix` function is for editing data objects, where `[<-` comes in to play.  of course, you can in fact do `body(myfunc)[10] <- 'my_var<-sin(your_var)' ` as well:-)